# How to check who uses certain port in C#?

Tags: c#, networking, port, tcp

How to determine what process/what executable is using, say, port 80 of my localhost? I would like to know, for example if it is Apache Server, etc.

Can we get some information from ipProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners() ? I've only seen local endpoint, remote endpoint and state.

Answer (score 5):

You can pipe the output of `netstat -o` and parse it, but that's probably a terrible idea full of headaches and edge cases.

Behind the scenes, `netstat -o` uses the [GetTcpTable2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API method from the IPHelper library, which returns a MIB_TCPTABLE2 structure, with each port represented by a MIB_TCPROW2 structure. You'll have to use P/Invoke to access this from C#, building interop structs for the table and the row

Checking PInvoke.Net, I see that a similar API call has already been mapped to C# - [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi/GetExtendedTcpTable.html) - which lists available TCP ports for an app. You can use that as a base for building your interop structs and declarations.