# listen to specific port c#

Tags: c#, .net, port, listen

I want to listen specific port in c#, but I don't want to write a chat program in net.
I just want listen to a port and receive all of the bytes that come from that port.
I asked this question before but I did't get a useful answer. I say again, I don't want to have a client and server program, I want to just have a single program that run on my Computer and show me what bytes are received from specific port, or a program that show me what IP is connected to each port , like "netstat" command in CMD.(I don't want to use CMD command in my C# program)
please help me.

Comment: Read up on using sockets in C#. All you would do is create a listening socket on the specified port, and do whatever you want with the data when it comes in. Have you tried anything? Have you written any code? StackOverflow helps people who help them self ;)

Comment: As to the last part of your question - check out the question here about using the APIs behind netstat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110211/how-to-check-who-uses-certain-port-in-c/9110360#9110360

Comment: "I asked this question before but I did't get a useful answer"...it might be helpful to post the url of the prior question you asked for reference

Comment: Kitsune: I write program, and tried so much, but I can't do it currently .....

Comment: @Mostafa When asking for help with a program (or anything else, really), it's best to tell us what you've tried, how it's worked, and SPECIFIC issues you've run into.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should get you started.  This will show you similar information to `netstat`:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

static void Main()
{

    IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnections = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

    foreach (TcpConnectionInformation tcpConnection in tcpConnections)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Local Address {0}:{1}\nForeign Address {2}:{3}\nState {4}",
                        tcpConnection.LocalEndPoint.Address,
                        tcpConnection.LocalEndPoint.Port,
                        tcpConnection.RemoteEndPoint.Address,
                        tcpConnection.RemoteEndPoint.Port,
                        tcpConnection.State);
    }
}
```

To listen to a port, the sample code provided by Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx) should get you going.

Comment: @Mostafa Do you require any more detail to accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need a sniffer. Check [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) out.